# "Failed to load database information" when running a crystal report using crexporter

Tags: pdf, crystal-reports

I built a report in Crystal Report 2013 and need to run it using crexport. The report ran w/o any problems in CR 2013 but when it was run in crexport I received this message

> Error : Failed to load database information.

Below are the contents from the log file. I appreciate any advises. Thanks in advance!

```
Crystal Reports Exporter version 2.1.11.1103

creport parameters : -F C:\Junk\Crystal\2014 Charts by Hospital FINAL2.rpt -O C:\Junk\Crystal\\2014 Charts by Hospital FINAL2.pdf -E pdf -l -a HospitalID:xxxxxxx (I intentionally removed the hospital number) -a Start Date:11/1/2014 -a End Date:11/30/2014 

Instantiated ReportDocument object

Crystal Reports file C:\Junk\Crystal\2014 Charts by Hospital FINAL2.rpt loaded

Database id = 0

Integrated Security = False

Default Server Name = C:\Junk\Crystal\B2014.mdb

Default Database Name = C:\Junk\Crystal\B2014.mdb

Integrated Security = true 

Integrated Security = true 

Report Output format set to : pdf

Report attribute : HasSavedData = False

Discrete Parameter : HospitalID = xxxxxxx
```

> Error : Failed to load database information.Error in File 2014 Charts
>   by Hospital FINAL2 {AB15DB0B-AB85-4E40-BECC-5E6416B7EFC5}.rpt:Failed
>   to load database information. ReportDocument closed

BTW, I followed the instructions from the link below and installed the crexport and associated programs.

http://www.itsupportguides.com/crystal-reports/crystal-reports-run-and-email-report-using-crexport-and-blat/

Answer (score 0):

Using integrated security doesn't make sense with MS Access databsae. Try to set user name. If you did not set password use user name "Admin".
Best will be to contact their customer support, if they have one. You can also check some more popular tools on [Ken Hamady's website](http://kenhamady.com/cru/comparisons/desktop-scheduling-engines) .I guess they will work with less issues because they have more customers. Some like Crystal Delivery 10 and R-Tag Report Manager are free.